# Can Doctrine 1.2 generate entity files with tabs instead of spaces?

Tags: coding-style, doctrine, whitespace

For a specific project, the entire code base uses tabs, not spaces.

Of course, **this is wrong**, everyone knows that. But in this particular project Doctrine breaks the coding convention by doing things **the right way** and creating entity files with spaces.

How can Doctrine 1.2 be configured to use tabs?

Comment: Why the hell would you use spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: I don't think this can be a configuration requirement for a project in a common way.

Comment: Coding convention of generated files? You must do something wrong with coding standards. Are you sure you don't have social problems in your project? And what about `cat`'ing the files through `sed` when building them?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `$this->spaces` to something else, e.g. `$this->spaces = "\t";` in [EntityGenerator.php](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php#L426).

You can also change the templates (e.g. [`getMethodTemplate`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.4/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php#L218)) to suit your brace placement preferences.

Note that this violates the [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/2/), which requires 4 spaces for indentation.